# Koa Session access store client connection from context

Tags: node.js, session, redis, koa

I'm using nodejs with koa as framework, plus koa-session and koa-redis.

```js
import Koa from 'koa';
...
import session from 'koa-session';
import redisStore from 'koa-redis';

const app = new Koa();
app.keys = ["cookieKeys"];
app.use(session({
  maxAge: 5184000000,
  store: redisStore({url: 'redis://localhost:6379'})
}, app));

...
const server = app.listen(1339, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port: 1339`);
});

export default server;
```

Now it's possible to set `ctx.session.key = "value";` and get `ctx.sessios.key;` on redis, because the connection is already estabelished.

How i can access the same redis client used on the koa-session store in other module? Right now I'm creating a new connection:

```js
import { Context, Next, Middleware } from 'koa';
import redis from 'koa-redis';

export default async (ctx: Context, next: Next): Promise<Middleware> => {
    try {
        return await next();
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.status !== 401) {
            throw err;
        }
        const redisClient = await redis({url: 'redis://localhost:6379'}).client;
        const tokenAccess = ctx.cookies.get('tokenAccess', {signed: true});
        const tokenRefresh = ctx.session.tokenRefresh;
        ...

        const isRefreshTokenRevoked = Number.isInteger(await redisClient.zrank('blacklist', tokenRefresh));
        await redisClient.quit();
        if (isRefreshTokenRevoked) {
            throw err;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I found this property inside context `ctx.session._sessCtx.store.client`. Is correct to use this property for that purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess my question jumped a few steps. I re-writed the code with a `db.js` file and put my redis connection as a singleton:

```
import { redisURI } from './config';
import Redis from 'koa-redis';

export const redisStore = Redis({url: redisURI});
```

So now I could import this connection and use on `index.js` and other files:

```js
import Koa from 'koa';
...
import session from 'koa-session';
import { redisStore } from './db';
//import redisStore from 'koa-redis';

const app = new Koa();
app.keys = ["cookieKeys"];
app.use(session({
  maxAge: 5184000000,
  store: redisStore
//store: redisStore({url: 'redis://localhost:6379'})
}, app));

...
const server = app.listen(1339, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port: 1339`);
});

export default server;
```

Imported on another module:

```js
import { Context, Next, Middleware } from 'koa';
import { redisStore } from './db';

export default async (ctx: Context, next: Next): Promise<Middleware> => {
    try {
        return await next();
    } catch (err) {
        if (err.status !== 401) {
            throw err;
        }
        //const redisClient = await redis({url: 'redis://localhost:6379'}).client;
        const tokenAccess = ctx.cookies.get('tokenAccess', {signed: true});
        const tokenRefresh = ctx.session.tokenRefresh;
        ...
        const isRefreshTokenRevoked = Number.isInteger(await redisStore.client.zrank('blacklist', tokenRefresh));
        //const isRefreshTokenRevoked = Number.isInteger(await redisClient.zrank('blacklist', tokenRefresh));
        //await redisClient.quit();
        if (isRefreshTokenRevoked) {
            throw err;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```